# PHP. Автозагрузка файлов

Tags: php

я студент, делаю практическую работу по PHP. Препод сказал изменить автозагрузку. Я не пойму, что он хочет от меня. Два раза переспрашивал. Сейчас боюсь опять спросить скажет тупой.

Ответы препода:

1. Нужен автолоадер для классов. По сути у вас require_once имеет право использоваться только в index.php и autoloader.php. Причем в index.php для того, чтобы подключить autoloader.php

- Мой уточняющий вопрос

  - У меня в проекте подключен composer, где настроена автозагрузка классов из папки app (где вся логика находится). Мне нужно сделать поверх этой автозагрузки свою логику? Или отчистить composer и сделать свою автозагрузку?

  Ответ препода:

  2. У вас получается сейчас реализовано так, что автолоадером подключаются не все файлы и это как-то не очень выглядит. Это просто непонятно зачем так сделано. Должны подключаться все.
- Структура проекта, директории

  - app (Controllers, DB, Router, Services)
  - config (разные конфиг файлы)
  - public (index.php)
  - routes (routes.php)
  - views
- Файл Composer

  ```
    {
      "name": "storage/app",
      "description": "graduate_work",
      "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
        "app\\": "app/",
         }
      },
      "authors": [
        {
          "name": ""
        }
      ],
      "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.8"
      },
      "require-dev": {
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.19",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.3",
        "rector/rector": "^0.17.2"
      }
    }
  ```
- Я понимаю, что выглядит глупо, но можете помочь мне, простыми словами объяснить, что не так. У меня все работает, подгружается куда нужно.

Comment: если я правильно понял.. когда-то делал тест задание куда-то) тут простая реализация https://github.com/joewcode/todolist

Comment: Бежал бы я подальше от такого препода... Можно добавить через [classmap](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) или [files](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) остальные файлы/классы

Comment: @InDevX сейчас всякие скиллбоксы/фэктари... там преподают те кого самого с работы выгнали из-за не компетентности) Нормальный спец никогда не будет тратить свое время за те деньги что там платят) там даже студенты вполне преподают)

Comment: Все верно указали, моя недоработка в плане понимания composer/autoload. Добавил иные файлы и классы через files и classmaps в composer и сейчас тестирую работу приложения.  Спасибо, что оперативно отреагировали на мой вопрос.

Comment: чтобы понимать о чём речь, надо видеть код....которого тут нет... может ты  якобы настроил автолоад, а по факту в файлах у тебя везде require написан. нам это неведомо

Comment: "*боюсь опять спросить скажет тупой.*" --- а то, что мы скажем, что ты **** это ничё, да?)) Надо не бояться спрашивать....какая разница что он подумает? Ты же не для него учишься, а для себя

Comment: Без ошибок невозможно ничему научиться.

Comment: Откуда ты узнал на счет require?) Действительно, были подключены конфиг файлы через require. Все исправил через внедрениt директив file и classmap в composer.

Comment: "*Откуда ты узнал на счет require?)*" --- тебе это препод написал в комментарии.

Comment: А вообще подключать прям всё всё всё через автолоад - бред. Например конфигурационный файл  можно и самому заrequire'ить в index файле. В этом ничего страшного нет...  если например посмотреть во фреймворк Yii2, то там вообще есть строчечки интересные `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

$config = require __DIR__ . '/../config/web.php';

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();`  ( https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/web/index.php ) ..... и ничего...живы здоровы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а препод говорит так нельзя ;(

Comment: @InDevX тут конечно надо смотреть по ситуации.. Если это типа а-ля гикбрейнс, где связь через комменты, где препод может раз в неделю ответ дать - ну приёдтся подстроится, но в голове держать, что препод балбес))  А если это препод института, с постоянной свзью, лично я бы аргументировал бы и продавливал свою позицию))

Comment: Буду более решительным при продавливании своей позиции.